# Twilio - The From phone number xxx is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

I want to use Twilio for verifying phone number of users registering on my app.
As a backend, I have Parse.

I tried to send an SMS using the test credentials, so far I received a success message, but, I didn't received the SMS!
I've tried to switch to the live credentials; however, I received the following:

```
{
    "code": 141,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "The From phone number +12025550162 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.",
        "code": 21606,
        "moreInfo": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21606"
    }
}
```

I've also tried to replace the "From" Phone number to an alphanumeric sender ID, but that didn't work too!

What should I do in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Firstly, test credentials don't actually send messages, they are simply there to test that you are making your API requests properly. Also note that [they only work with specific numbers and only on a few endpoints](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials).

In order to [send SMS messages from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), you need to buy and use a number from Twilio as your "From" number. Your number there doesn't look as though it is a Twilio number. You can [buy numbers from your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search).

My guess is that you're sending messages to US numbers. Alphanumeric sender IDs don't work in the US I'm afraid, you can [see the countries that support it here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id).

Finally, if you're looking to verify your users' numbers, have you checked out [Authy](https://authy.com)? They do [phone verification as an API](http://docs.authy.com/phone_verification.html), as well as two factor authentication.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided! After following your recommendation, it works fine now ;)

Comment: Cane we use From number with short numbers like "12345" instead of alphanumeric sender ids. When I did that it shows me "The From phone number 123456 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or shortcode for your account." @philnash

Comment: @Lakshmi you can, but you need to buy a short code, same as a long code. Check out the details here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes

Comment: Shouldn't the test API key allow sending the message, and at least send it to the `Monitor - Log` section

Comment: When using the test API key, you will receive a successful API response (status 200) when it would send correctly. But no actual messages are logged.